# Unable to web deploy an application that is using a Managed Service Account

Tags: iis, active-directory, web-deployment

I have configured an IIS application pool (win server 2012 r2) to use an active directory managed service account without any issues, but I cannot publish this application from Visual Studio using Web Publish. I use my own credentials to publish to the website, and the folder structure gets created properly, but then I see this error:

> Web deployment task failed. ((2014-10-07 12:45:44 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (2014-10-07 12:45:44 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
>   The account 'mydomain\iismsa$' does not appear to be valid. The account was obtained from this location: 'system.applicationHost/applicationPools/MyWebApp'.
>   Some or all identity references could not be translated.
>   at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
>   at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)
>   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Impersonator.GetNTAccount(String userName, String source)

I have already granted full permissions to the service account on the target folder on the server.

Has anyone successfully used a managed service account to run IIS app pool AND been able to publish remotely?